# How to make my SPA works without a framework using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I've been developing a web application using jQuery, and I'm using ajax to make a SPA.

Basically I have a menu on the left side of the page and the content on the right side. Every time the user clicks on a menu option I make a ajax call embedding the html content of the corresponding page inside the div "content".

These pages have links too and that also make ajax calls to load other pages, so I've append the content of the `script.js` and everything worked well. I developed the entire application using this solution.

The problem is...: when I started the integrated tests I noticed the application slow down as the clicks on the links, probably caused by the embedded content.

I don't want rewrite the entire application using a framework just because of that.

**index.html**

```
<body>    
<div id="menu">    
   <a class="menu-option" href="templates/page1.html">
     Page 1
   </a>

   <a class="menu-option" href="templates/page2.html">
     Page 2
   </a>

   <a class="menu-option" href="templates/page3.html">
     Page 3
   </a>    
</div>      
<div id="content"></div>       
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
   $('.menu-option').on('click', function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageRef = $(this).attr('href');

        callPage(pageRef);    
    })    
});

function callPage(pageRefInput) {    
    $.ajax({    
        url: pageRefInput,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'text',    
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log('the page was loaded');

            console.log(response);

            $('#content').html(response);    
        },            
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log('the page was NOT loaded', error);
        },    
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            console.log("The request is completed!");

            var item = '<script class="script">var url = "js/script.js";$.getScript(url);</script>';                  
            $('#content').append(item);  
        },    
    });    
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good question but a poor fit for stack overflow. The answer (how to make a performant SPA) could and has filled entire books.

Comment: Are the console.logs in your final version?

Comment: Take a look @ `jQuery`'s [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function. it will do what you are trying to do. (_I think you should consider using react or similar frameworks though_)

Comment: @JaredSmith you're right!

Comment: @AndreNuechter it's just for testing

Comment: @MehdiDehghani thanks! I usually work with vue... The problem is... I couldn't use vue in this project, this is a customer restriction... They can only afford a basic JS developer...

Comment: Like the other comments, I'd heavily suggest using a framework  such as React or Vue and both can be intertwined gradually in an existing App, support is also high for both frameworks.